# Telepathy and what Islam says about it?

Tags: blessings-of-allah

** Asslam o' alikum. I want to know Islam says about telepathy? Also if you are allowed to do it and do no bad action whilst doing it, is it okay because your not doing anything wrong?**
What does the Hadith say about it?